# SQL db query: how to add a new field and assign values

Tags: query

I have 3 tables as shown in the screenshot below. I have created a query using UNION as shown below.

[image]

```
SELECT T1_ID AS ID, T1_NAME AS NAME, T1_ADD AS ADDRESS
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT T2_ID AS ID, T2_NAME AS NAME, T2_ADD AS ADDRESS
FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT T3_ID AS ID, T3_NAME AS NAME, T3_ADD AS ADDRESS
FROM Table3
```

And I got the result below.

[image]

My question is, how do I add a column (field) called TYPE and assign values to the query results but not updating the existing three tables to make it like the screenshot below?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant of solutions, but to answer your question, you could do this:

```
SELECT T1_ID AS ID, T1_NAME AS NAME, T1_ADD AS ADDRESS, 'ANIMAL' AS TYPE
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT T2_ID AS ID, T2_NAME AS NAME, T2_ADD AS ADDRESS, 'HUMAN' AS TYPE
FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT T3_ID AS ID, T3_NAME AS NAME, T3_ADD AS ADDRESS, 'OBJECT' AS TYPE
FROM Table3
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, this works.